# Spring Security Web application context doesn't load beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

## Problem

I can't load beans from `spring-beans.xml` in addition to programmatic configuration. I've created a custom `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and annotated the class with the following annotations: `@Configuration, @ImportResource('classpath*:spring-beans.xml'), @EnableWebSecurity`. As you can see in the logs, no beans are loaded. Why? My goal ist o have a semi flexible configuration. I want to configure some parts in code and some parts in the spring-beans.xml file which should be loaded into the application context on startup. For example i want to define a custom AuthentificationProvider and create it with a custom configuration in the spring-beans.xml file. Whats done with the provider should be fixed in code.

### Logs

```
[INFO] 2018-10-23 14:48:05,569 TRACE (Default Executor-thread-11) [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(findAllClassPathResources:322)] Resolved classpath location [spring-beans.xml] to resources []
[INFO] 2018-10-23 14:48:05,573 TRACE (Default Executor-thread-11) [XmlBeanDefinitionReader(loadBeanDefinitions:229)] Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:spring-beans.xml]
```

### Javacode

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:spring-beans.xml"})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // configuration creates a servlet filter known as 'springSecurityFilterChain'

    @Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // configure some http stuff
    }

}
```

### spring-beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="myProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="myProvider"
      class="package.providers.MyProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="arg1" />
    <constructor-arg value="arg2" />
</bean>


</beans>
```

## Dependencies

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Update 1

### Project Structure

The project is a standard maven folder structure

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   ├── META-INF
│   │   │   └── spring
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   └── test
│       └── java
```

### Editing of Javacode

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/resources/spring/spring-beans.xml"})
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // configuration creates a servlet filter known as 'springSecurityFilterChain'

    @Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // configure some http stuff
    }

}
```

After updating the code, the log stays the same saying: '...Loaded 0 beans...'.

Answer (score 1):

Providing folder structure of your application will help to answer this question correctly.

Meanwhile you can try below solution-

Assuming that file is not in any jar, in `@ImportResource({"classpath*:spring-beans.xml"})`, specify absolute path to the bean definition file. eg: `@ImportResource({"classpath:/configurations/spring-beans.xml"})`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've tried your suggestions, but they unfortunately didn't fixed the problem.
Please see the update in my post for the project structure.

Comment: Let me try with this proj structure and come back.

Comment: Your classpath should be just "/spring/spring-beans.xml" - the resources folder is a Maven organizational feature, it is not kept when the code is put in the target folder.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem.

Comment: @oops You need not change folder structure. Keep your `spring` folder under resources directory. Only remove **/resources** from import resources. 
eg: `@ImportResource({"classpath:/spring/spring-beans.xml"})`

Comment: This answer seems more accurate. There's no need to move your `spring` folder outside of `resources`. In fact, `resources` is the exact location for your config files.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to [@moilejter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360035/moilejter)**

To fix the problem i just needed to move the directory.

Structure before fix

```
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        └── resources
            ├── META-INF
            └── spring
```

**Solution**

```
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── resources
        │   └── META-INF
        └── spring
```